# Back Button not appering on page navigation Template-10?

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, template10

I'm using Hamburger template of Template-10 for my UWP app. I created few pages but when I navigate through those pages the back button doesn't get visible. Even on using `NavigationService.Navigate()` method it doesn't appear. I want back button to be visible when I navigate through the pages. Do I need to register that a navigation has occurred whenever I move to different page? Please help.

Comment: Did you modified the template?

Comment: In the generated template, the back button visibile after navigation in desktop mode by default in the title bar. Could you provide some info which version do you use?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? Without any code, it's hard for us to find where your problem is.

Comment: @mvermef Thanks for the help, Setting `ClearHistory="False"` soled it :)

Answer (score 0):

`ClearHistory = "False"` on the control?